# Working out the power in a circuit when the current and voltage are in trigonometric waveform.

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on an applied math assignment and this particular question is bugging me. 
The problem states:
*The power, $p$, in an electrical circuit is quantified by $p=iv$.*
This problem wants me to show the following:

1. If $i=Isin(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $v=Vsin(\omega t)$ then $p=-\frac{IV}{2}cos(2\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})$

Here is what I did so far:
$$Isin(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})Vsin(\omega t)$$
Using the identity: $sin(A-B)=sin(A)cos(B)-cos(A)sin(B)$
$$Isin(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})=I[sin(\omega t)cos(\frac{\pi}{2})-cos(\omega t)sin(\frac{\pi}{2})]$$
$$I[0-cos(\omega t)(1)]$$
$$\therefore -Icos(\omega t) $$
$$-Icos(\omega t)Vsin(\omega t)$$
$$-IVcos(\omega t)sin(\omega t)$$
I am stuck at this point and I don't really know where to go next. I noticed that I also took out the $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is supposed to be part of my final answer. Have I selected the correct identity? Are there better ways of getting my way around these type of problems?

Comment: Do you know the double angle formula ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes! How can I apply it in this scenario?

Comment: Sorry, but it is in front of your eyes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @YvesDaoust Do I have to equate $Isin(\omega t-\phi/2)Vsin(\omega t)$ to $cos^2(x)-sin^2(x)$?

Comment: That's doable, but there is a simpler way.

Comment: I'll try. I'm still stuck with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the product to sum formula $$\sin A \sin B = \frac {1}{2}[\cos (A - B) - \cos (A + B)]$$ with $A = \omega t - \pi/2$ and $B = \omega t$.  What do you notice?

Comment: Oh! Its clear now! Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad to help!  I think the "what do you notice?" was the key because one term vanishes - namely $\cos \pi/2$, which equals $0$.

Comment: Yes! You know I actually love it when the argument in $cos()$ is either $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $90$ :D Makes life easy haha